# each drag element drop on each drop box

Tags: jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/yv4wnmq4/5/

I have been asked to make some drag and drop functionality

**[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTc6k.png)** 
condition 1

each drag element will drop on each drop box

condition 2

drag elements should keep on same place after drag

```
 $(function () {
    $(".container2").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var itemid = $(event.originalEvent.toElement).attr("itemid");
    var $dragged = ui.draggable,
      $draggedClone = $dragged.clone();
    $('.box-item').each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("itemid") === itemid) {
        if ($this.find("div").attr("itemid") != itemid) {
          $this.append($draggedClone);
        }


      }
    });
  }
});
$('.box-item').draggable({
  cursor: 'move',
  helper: "clone"
});
});
```

Comment: have you read the jquery ui documentation?

Comment: no i dont have read

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/yv4wnmq4/3/

Comment: in each drop box only one item will accept

Comment: @swaroopkomma what?

Comment: Not sure what it is your want. but try this https://jsfiddle.net/yv4wnmq4/5/. Without being more clear i cant help

Comment: image attached,once see my question

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTc6k.png